# How to redirect a specific image to a specific URL if called directly?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect a specific image to a specific URL if it is browsed directly. The following is not working:

```
Redirect 301 /images/image1.jpg /page.html
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

### [Edit]

Below is my entire htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /item.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php

ErrorDocument 400 /error/
ErrorDocument 403 /error/
ErrorDocument 404 /error/
ErrorDocument 405 /error/
ErrorDocument 408 /error/
ErrorDocument 500 /error/
ErrorDocument 502 /error/
ErrorDocument 504 /error/

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^/includes/content/upload/tarantula-spider-dog-costume-459.jpg$ /tarantula-spider-dog-costume [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=2
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/outdoors? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=3
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/pet-stuff? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=4
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/geeky-stuff? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=5
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/toys? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=6
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/apparel? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=7
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/ridiculous? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=8
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/kid-stuff? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=9
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/food-drink? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=10
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/home-kitchen? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=11
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/gag-gifts? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=12
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/books? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=13
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/halloween? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=14
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/christmas? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=15
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/valentines-day? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=16
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/link-roundup? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=1
RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /categories/gadgets? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Just give the link to the image

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that...

Comment: What URL is not redirecting? Is this the only rule or you have other rules also?

Comment: I just added my htaccess file to the description, the one that's not working starts on line 19.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/image1.jpg$ page.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

You can test it at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be

### [Edit]

According to your edit, update the line 19 as below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^includes/content/upload/tarantula-spider-dog-costume-459.jpg$ /tarantula-spider-dog-costume [R=301,NC,L]
```

Remove the leading slash from `^/includes...` and add `R=301`. It works when I test it in the .htaccess tester I mentioned above.

Comment: Actually I think my .htaccess file is not even updating. I change something that's currently in it, and it does nothing... Any ideas on that?

Comment: @RandyLahey Is your `.htaccess` file at the same level along with `images/`?

Comment: Yup, it's right at the root. It works for the many redirects I already have in place, but I just can't change anything, it won't update. It's like it's cached.

Comment: @RandyLahey May be your rule at the top most is wrong or you could have `[NC,L]` which stops the next rule to process. Can you please add all of your rules in your question?

Comment: I added the htaccess file to the description above. The one that's not working starts on line 19.

Comment: @RandyLahey please check my edit in the answer according to your updated description.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^/images/image1.jpg$ /page.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything, when I go to the image directly it just stays on the image.

Answer (score 0):

**My understanding**

**1.** The `image1.jpg` should always be shown when included in your site's pages.

**2.** When called directly by the image's URL, instead of showing the image, it should show the contents of the html page `page.html` using one of the two options below:

- **A**) Keep the same image URL in the browser but show only the
  `page.html` content (when `page.html` does not include `image1.jpg`).
- **B**) Change the URL in the browser by redirecting to `page.html` (This
  page may include `image1.jpg`)

---

#### RewriteRule For 2A

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^images/image1.jpg$ page.html [NC,L]
```

#### RewriteRule For 2B

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^images/image1.jpg$  page.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Images are usually cached by browsers. Clear you browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it still doesn't seem to be changing anything. I attached the entire htaccess file above. The line that's not working starts on line 19.